# О предикате  "Мама мыть окно в [момент времени] t."

Tags: синтаксис

Даны три высказывания:

- "Мама мыла окно.",
- "Мама моет окно.",
- "**Мама** будет **мыть** **окно**.".

Верно ли, что каждое из указанных предложений образуется с помощью надлежащей кванторизации предиката "**Мама мыть окно** в [момент времени] t." по [прошлому, настоящему и будущему] подмножествам времени T?

Answer (score 3):

Не знаю, что такое кванторизация предиката. Но знаю, что предикативной основой являются: мама мыла, мама моет, мама будет мыть. Сказуемое фактически одно и то же, только в разных временах . Слово "окно" не входит в основу, это дополнение.

Comment: 1. Спасибо.

2. См. http://www.wikiznanie.ru/ru-wz/index.php/Квантор